# SQL Server Permissions - Assign user to group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions

Is there a way in which I can create groups in SQL which I can add users in so permissions can be updated to the group rather than multiple individual users. I am looking to assign database permissions.

Comment: See `CREATE ROLE` in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Roles**

> Roles are database-level securables. After you create a role,
>   configure the database-level permissions of the role by using GRANT,
>   DENY, and REVOKE and you may add users as its members.

When working with SQL Logins you "group" them by using roles within SQL Server. Roles are created at the database-level but with SQL Server 2012 you will be able to create them at the server-level as well.

Once the role is created you can assign specific permissions to that group and it will be applied to the logins that are member of that role. The roles are localized to the instance you are under and are not visible or accessible to remote instances. You will only be able to add the logins in that instance of SQL Server to the roles.

[How to create role ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql)

I hope be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You shoul create a `database role`

[Database-Level Roles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121(v=sql.110).aspx)

And then use [sp_addrolemember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750(v=sql.110).aspx) or [ALTER ROLE (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775(v=sql.110).aspx) (depends on version you are on) to add users to the role.

Then you grant the permissions to that role